# Hive Mysql Metastore Row lock increases

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, big-data

Below is the query causing row locks in Mariadb Galera Cluster 10.2.32 (3Node Cluster).

```
select MT_COMMENT from AUX_TABLE where MT_KEY1='Cleaner' and MT_KEY2=0 for update
```

- Hive is a framework, we couldn't get the flow to understand also can't alter the logic from app end.
- Looking for solutions like any version that works in Mysql/Postgresql or any Metastore DBs that can scale for Hive Metastore without lockign issues.
- Also looking for any work around solution from DB end for this Mysql Row Locking.